# How to change schedule of backup jobs using SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005, database, sql, ssms

I have an SQL Server 2005 on our lab network, I installed MS SQL Management studio on separate computer to connect to the SQL Server to schedule a backup job of a few database. It worked fine for the backup jobs as scheduled, my question is how am I going to edit the backup job's schedule to change the starting time of the backup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the job was scheduled as part of a maintenance plan, you can edit the steps of the maintenence plan. If the job was not scheduled as part of a maintenance plan, then expand the SQL Server Agent node and select the Jobs node and edit your job in the right pane of Object Explorer.